# How the Execution States works in iOS

Tags: ios, view, screen

Intially,If i open the open the app first time it shows this screen.Because i didnt add any connection.

After i add the connection using plus button.It shows the overall electricity consumption screen.
[image]

Then,If i close the app and open the app means,it shows the electricity consumption screen.
[image]

1.How it works?

2.What are all the execution States?

3..How to do this,Give me some idea?
I have read the execution States in Apple Docs,But didn't get clear idea.Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) is pretty nice, including diagrams. What do you have trouble understanding in the "Execution States for Apps" section? Are you aware that instead of "closing" the app, you are putting it into background and then bringing it into foreground again, thereby execution pauses but doesn't stop?

Comment: First of all this screen shots is in android not for iOS but still you want problem for foreground and background concept please apple documentation.

Comment: Just am Closing the app.I am not putting it into backgroud.How the first screen resigns if i open the app.@DarkDust

Comment: I have to do this is in iOS,So only putting android screenshots.I have gone through the apple Docs @Nimit.Provide me a step by step Execution state.Thanks in Advance!!